# How to modify panels individually in a wxPython wizard?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxwidgets, wxpython

I am quite new to wxPython and want to build a wizzard. I used [this](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/12/wxpython-how-to-create-a-generic-wizard/) guide as a base ("wxPython: How to Create a Generic Wizard"). I tried to add some widgets the panel, e.g. some radio buttons at the second page by inserting the following code at line 56 in  add_page():

```
 if(title=="Page 2"):
            k1=wx.RadioButton(panel,-1,'Argument1',(35,60),(150,20), style = wx.RB_GROUP)
            k2=wx.RadioButton(panel,-1,'Argument2',(35,80),(150,20))
```

But as soon as I try to add some sizer to the the second panel, all pages are affected. I tried quite a few variations of where to place the sizers, but without success. So my question is: is this the appropriate place to modify the individual pages and could someone give me a hint of how to write a minimalistic example of e.g inserting a boxSizer and a button in the first page and a boxSizer and a RadioButton in the second page?

Comment: Few people are going to bother to juggle between 2 sets of code. It would be better if you edited your question to include the code that you are working on. This also includes errors you may have introduced, unwittingly.

Comment: @Baltasar, also, if you could please explain what yuo mean by saying `all pages are affected` it would be great. One can only guess...

Comment: Someone (enlightened) erased my answer. Here is the solution to your problems with wizards:  http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/01/27/wxpython-a-wizard-tutorial/